# QueryRow().Scan() returns error if row doesn't exist

Tags: go

I want to fetch one row from an sql database. I use the following code:

```
var name string
row := db.Con().QueryRow("SELECT name FROM users WHERE id = 2;")
err := row.Scan(&name)

if err != nil {
    // log the error
}
```

For example: if a user with `id=2` doesn't exist, then the method `Scan` returns an error.

**Question:**

Is there a way to avoid this error when a row doesn't exist? Because it's absolutely normal and I don't want to log such errors.

The only way I found is to use `Query` instead of `QueryRow`, but it is not convenient because I have to add `for rows.Next() { ..` every time when I want to fetch single row.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Simply check for the error you don't want to log before logging:

```
var name string
row := db.Con().QueryRow("SELECT name FROM users WHERE id = 2;")
err := row.Scan(&name)

if err != nil && err != sql.ErrNoRows {
    // log the error
}
```

Comment: you can use sql.NullString instead of string, that should not output an error.

Comment: You can actually just omit the parameter passed to row.Scan() entirely.

Comment: @kmac.mcfarlane I think that is no possible, at least now, as it causes `number of field descriptions must equal number of destinations`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just scan the returned row, I check first that it is not nil.

```
if row != nil {
  err := row.Scan()
}
```

I think you can also use pgx v4 for your db driver and it doesn't return no rows as an error.

Comment: Eh, excessive: 
`// QueryRow executes a query that is expected to return at most one row.
// QueryRow always returns a non-nil value. Errors are deferred until
// Row's Scan method is called.`